# JQuery Loops only Evaluating First Item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have went through a majority of the answers similar to this question and have tried different implementations with no luck. You will see in my code there are multiple things commented out where I have tried different ways. However, none have worked for me.

```
 <script>
    function GenerateRandomColor(ele) {
        var colors = ["red", "orange", "blueviolet", "darkorchid", "midnightblue", "lightblue", "aqua", "darkgreen","lime", "orangered"];
        ele.css('color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*9)]);
        ele.css('font-weight', bold);
        //return;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var elements = $(".impt");
        var colors = ["red", "orange", "blueviolet", "darkorchid", "midnightblue", "lightblue", "aqua", "darkgreen","lime", "orangered"];
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
            var element = elements.eq(i);
            //do something with element'
            element.css('color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*9)]);
            element.css('font-weight', bold);
            //continue;
            //GenerateRandomColor(element);
        }
        /*var spanObjs = document.querySelectorAll('.impt');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(spanObjs, function(elements, index) {
            GenerateRandomColor($(elements)); 
        });*/
        /*$('.impt').each(function(i, obj) {
            GenerateRandomColor($(obj)); 
        });*/
    });
</script>
```

All I am aiming for is: I have a paragraph, with multiple spans in it to emphasize a few of the important words in it. So the spans all have the class impt. I want to make the text color random and the words to all be bold.

All of the implementations are giving me the same result. The first span gets colored and bolded but that is all.

Comment: should not the lines starting "element.css...." not be " $(element).css....."

Comment: you need to put bold in quotes

Comment: @IvoP no.......

Comment: Always, *always* have your browser developer console open. In this case it would have saved you the time of creating this question because you would have seen the fairly clear error message: "bold is not defined".

Comment: Yes, Perfect that worked. Goodness I have tried so many different things. Thank You! I will post the corrected code below. How do I mark it as answered ?

Comment: @Pointy I was using my browser developer, breakpoints and everything and it was not giving me any errors. It succesfully went through everything once but that was all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put bold in quotes

https://jsfiddle.net/x4rsyh8n/

You should have your console open so you can see javascript errors in future.

```
<script>
    function GenerateRandomColor(ele) {
        var colors = ["red", "orange", "blueviolet", "darkorchid", "midnightblue", "lightblue", "aqua", "darkgreen","lime", "orangered"];
        ele.css('color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*9)]);
        ele.css('font-weight', 'bold');
        //return;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var elements = $(".impt");
        var colors = ["red", "orange", "blueviolet", "darkorchid", "midnightblue", "lightblue", "aqua", "darkgreen","lime", "orangered"];
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
            var element = elements.eq(i);
            //do something with element'
            element.css('color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*9)]);
            element.css('font-weight', 'bold');
            //continue;
            //GenerateRandomColor(element);
        }
        /*var spanObjs = document.querySelectorAll('.impt');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(spanObjs, function(elements, index) {
            GenerateRandomColor($(elements)); 
        });*/
        /*$('.impt').each(function(i, obj) {
            GenerateRandomColor($(obj)); 
        });*/
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add one thing to the code and it worked perfectly. Here is the updated code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var elements = $(".impt");
        var colors = ["red", "orange", "blueviolet", "darkorchid", "midnightblue", "lightblue", "aqua", "darkgreen","lime", "orangered"];
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
            var element = elements.eq(i);
            //do something with element'
            element.css('color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*9)]);
            element.css('font-weight', "bold");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Bold needed to be in quotes. Hopefully this will be of help to another!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues on your code:

**1)** `ele.css('font-weight', bold);` should be `ele.css('font-weight', 'bold');`

**2)** You can replace the harcoded length of `9` by getting the `colors` length, i.e, replace `Math.floor(Math.random()*9)` by this `Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length - 1))`

Finally, all your code can be summarized to this one:

```js
function GenerateRandomColor(ele)
{
    var colors = ["red", "orange", "blueviolet", "darkorchid", "midnightblue", "lightblue", "aqua", "darkgreen","lime", "orangered"];
    ele.css({
        'color': colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length - 1))],
        'font-weight': "bold"
    });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var elements = $(".impt");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        GenerateRandomColor(elements.eq(i));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>I'm some <spam class="impt">random</spam> text with <spam class="impt">ramdom</spam> colors</p>
```